# Is there a way to enable browser autofill on an AJAX loaded select?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I'm building an SPA (single page application) with React. A part of this application has a form containing two select inputs: one to fill in the country and a second for the state. The user would be able to select e.g. **United States** in the first select and **Georgia** in the second. The second list is dynamically updated when the country input `onChange` event is fired, based on a JSON file.

When the user is using the browser's autofill feature and has e.g. **Canada** as their country, the first input is filled as expected, however, the second is not. I guess that's because when the browser fills the form, the list of the states is not yet updated. There is a fraction of time between those moments.

Is there a way to workaround this behavior?

Comment: Could you maybe share some code that you tried? Because to me it seems weird that when you have an onchange function on your first select field which fills up the second select field based on the JSON file, that the second select field is not filled up when you trigger the onchange function of your first field.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden input for the state. It will hold the value with the browser's autofill, then when your second input is ready you can select the state.

Also when the second input changes you should change the hidden input too.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I'll try it now. Thanks!